# Android VideoView flickering

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a gallery with 2 view types: images and a layout with image and viewview. When I scroll through it and the item with videoview is created, whole screen flickers. I've tried inflating this item in adapter onCreate, but nothing changed. The flickering happens somewhere after the getView is called.

Comment: can you copy logcat or some code so we can check

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11016465/1326017 fixes the problem for me, but I'm still looking for a real fix, not a workaround.